# Force redirection to specific page on app load

Tags: angular, electron

I am trying to setup my Angular 2 application to go to the default route on page load regardless of the route its on but I can't seem to get it working.

I added logic to my app-component's ngOnInit to redirect to my home route but its being ignored.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  closeApplication() {
    electron.ipcRenderer.send('close-app');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('I am being run.');
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }

}
```

Here is my routing config

```
import {LoginComponent} from "./login/login.component";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";
import {AuthGuard} from "./shared/security/auth.guard";
import {RegisterComponent} from "./register/register.component";
import {ListingComponent} from "./listing/listing.component";
import {RedirectGuard} from "./shared/security/redirect.guard";
import {WelcomeComponent } from "./welcome/welcome.component";

export const routerConfig = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [RedirectGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [RedirectGuard] },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ListingComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'listing/:id',
        component: ListingComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

For some context, I am creating a Electron application that has a linear user flow which is working fantastic if the user starts the application on the default page. If I am on say page 3 and refresh, the entire applications state is all out of wack. I am not using a database to retain state and I think storing in local storage is too much of a burden for my end goal.

Cheers!

Comment: Please post your routing configuration.

Comment: There you go. I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just implemented the following architecture into a project where I created a `redirect.component` which resolved where the course should go post loading. The following is a super simplified version;

```
import { Component, OnInit }    from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-redirect',
  template: ``
})
export class RedirectComponent implements OnInit {
    private goDownPathOne: boolean = true;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if(goDownPathOne)
            this.router.navigate('path1');
        else
            this.router.navigate('path2');
  }

}
```

Then in my `app.routing` I have the following:

```
const COURSE_ROUTES: Routes = [
    // Home / Menu Screen
    { path: '', component: RedirectComponent },
    // Default Routes
    { path: 'screen', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'text', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'activity', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }

];

export const courseRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(COURSE_ROUTES);
```

So on app load, it always goes to the `RedirectComponent` which then decides where we should go on the data provided - in my case I dragged it down from a database. I am not sure if this is the optimal approach, however if defiinitely works!

Answer (score -1):

Try setting up a proper [router configuration](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html).
When configuring your routes you can also use [wildcards](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html#!#wild-cards) to setup [redirects](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#redirect):

`{path: '**', redirectTo: 'your-defaultPath', pathMatch:'full'}`

Check the full [routing docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) for more info on the angular2 router.

Here is a simple example with 'home' and 'other' routes. The empty ' ' route is redirected to 'home' and any non matching route is redirected to home.

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

@Component({selector: 'app', template: 'App Shell<br> <router-outlet></router-outlet>'})
export class AppComponent {}

@Component({selector:'home', template:'Home component'})
export class HomeComponent {}

@Component({selector:'other', template:'Other component'})
export class OtherComponent {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
      {path:'other', component: OtherComponent},
      {path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'},
      {path:'**', redirectTo:'home'}
    ], {enableTracing:true}) 
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, OtherComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Note that I set the enableTracing option to true to get more info on the navigation.

Comment: I already have routes setup. I added it up top. When I added your suggestion to the `**` path, the application acted the same. When I tried putting it on the path I wanted to redirect (home and its children) it just kept redirecting me back to `welcome` on any route changes to these pages.

Comment: I added a simple example - hope it helps. I would NOT recommend to do any redirects in ngOnInit. All route matching and redirecting should be placed in the router configuration.

Comment: I don't think this addressed my problem. I am trying to make it so if you refresh the application on any route it brings you to a specific route. When I implement you suggestion, when I refresh its just bringing me to the same route.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why should a refresh on route /a/b/c/d redirect to /x, obviously the user wants /a/b/c/d? What's the purpose of this redirect?